# Same scale for multiple series in Y-axis

Tags: jfreechart

I am using SpagoBI JFree Chart Engine,I am showing 5 series in my Y-axis.It is working fine but showing me different scale for each series.I want to have same scale for each series,and can I have the freedom in setting the scale in JFreeChart engine through Spago BI.
with regards
Sanjoy my code is like 
        {

```
 <!-- div properties -->
 <HIGHCHART  width='80%' height='80%'>

  <!-- chart object properties -->
  <CHART zoomType='xy' />

  <!-- title object properties --> 
  <TITLE text='Tenancy status For $P{Statename}'> 
  </TITLE>

  <!-- subtitle object properties --> 
  <SUBTITLE text='ALL RELATED TO AREA'> 
  </SUBTITLE>

    <X_AXIS   alias='stateyear' /> 

  <!-- yAxis object properties  -->
   <Y_AXIS_LIST>
    <Y_AXIS alias='AREA' opposite='true'>
        <LABELS>
            <STYLE  color='#89A54E' />
        </LABELS>
        <TITLE text='Total Area'>
          <STYLE  color='#89A54E' />
        </TITLE>
    </Y_AXIS>

    <Y_AXIS alias='WHOLLY_OWN' gridLineWidth='0' >
       <LABELS>
            <STYLE  color='#4572A7' />
        </LABELS>
        <TITLE text='WHOLLY OWN'>
          <STYLE  color='#4572A7' />
        </TITLE>
    </Y_AXIS>

     <Y_AXIS alias='WHOLLY_LEASED' gridLineWidth='0'  >
        <LABELS>
            <STYLE  color='#AA4643' />
        </LABELS>
        <TITLE text='WHOLLY LEASED'>
          <STYLE  color='#AA4643' />
        </TITLE>
    </Y_AXIS>

<Y_AXIS alias='OTHERWISE_OPERATED' gridLineWidth='0'  >
        <LABELS>
            <STYLE  color='#a94373' />
        </LABELS>
        <TITLE text='OTHERWISE OPERATED'>
          <STYLE  color='#a94373' />
        </TITLE>
    </Y_AXIS>

<Y_AXIS alias='TOTAL_PARTLY_AREAS' gridLineWidth='0' >
        <LABELS>
            <STYLE  color='#43a6a9' />
        </LABELS>
        <TITLE text='TOTAL PARTLY AREAS'>
          <STYLE  color='#43a6a9' />
        </TITLE>
    </Y_AXIS>


  </Y_AXIS_LIST>


  <!-- legend object properties -->
    <LEGEND layout='horizontal'
         align='left'
         verticalAlign='top'
         x='120'
         y='80'
         floating='true'
         borderWidth='1'
         backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'
         shadow='true'/>

  <SERIES_LIST allowPointSelect='true'>
            <SERIES name='Total Area' color='#89A54E' type='column' yAxis='1' alias='AREA' />
            <SERIES name='WHOLLY OWN' color='#4572A7' type='spline' alias='WHOLLY_OWN'  yAxis='2'/>
            <SERIES name='WHOLLY LEASED' color='#AA4643' type='spline' alias='WHOLLY_LEASED' yAxis='3' /> 
            <SERIES name='OTHERWISE OPERATED' color='#a94373' type='spline' alias='OTHERWISE_OPERATED' yAxis='4' />
            <SERIES name='TOTAL PARTLY AREAS' color='#43a6a9' type='spline' alias='TOTAL_PARTLY_AREAS'  />



    </SERIES_LIST>

</HIGHCHART>
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: My code is like the following, but I don't know what or where to write for getting same scale for multiple series